# Request: Readers to Check Accuracy of the History in my Young Adult Math Story

Tags: mathematicians

I'm writing a young adult math story, ***Althea and the Mystery of the Imaginary Numbers***.

Her mom tells her about Scipione del Ferro, Antonio Fior, Tartaglia, Cardano, and Ferrari. And they do some math together.

I hope it's ok to ask for help here. This seems like the best place to find math historians who might be willing to help me.

[Here's my current draft.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fteGsyrKFmU3nBf29q8HJlC1hnfmtYQX/view?usp=sharing)

Do I have the history right (pages 17 to 42)? I have done lots of research, but the sources disagree often. My original source for the story of the discovery/creation of the cubic formula is a chapter in Journey Through Genius.

Comment: (It would be helpful to know the reason for the downvote.)

Comment: I am not the downvoter (yet), but this request is overly broad and not a good fit for this Q&A site that restricts itself to *specific* focused questions to which factual answers can be provided within the space of a screen page or two. If you could narrow down the question to the specific issue you have the most doubts about, the question might be salvageable.

Comment: FWIW, the contents on the linked webpage does not seem to be accessible to the general public? When I clicked on the PDF, I got a status indicator "Working ...", but nothing else happened.

Comment: In case it helps, I recall reading one or more reviews of Nahin's book that were critical about certain historical details. Possibly looking over the the following reviews (ordered by publication date) could be of use to you: [American Scientist](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27857147) *AND* [Science](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2896949) *AND* [American Mathematical Monthly](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589485) *AND* [Notices of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/199910/rev-blank.pdf?) **(continued)**

Comment: *AND* [Mathematical Gazette](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3620988) *AND* [Isis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/237333) *AND* [Mathematical Gazette](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40378701) (2007 paperback edition; also [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1106.01002)). Incidentally, a new preface in the 2007 paperback edition (FYI, I only have a copy of the original 1998 edition, but you can see the new preface [here](https://www.amazon.com/Imaginary-Tale-Princeton-Science-Library/dp/0691169241)) discusses some of the changes made due to reader/reviewer comments.

Comment: Seems to me that "Do I have the history right?" in relation to a specific history like the one identified here (if the link can be made to work) is a question that it would be both sensible and generous to welcome. If I could have contributed  anything useful I would have beeen glad to.

Comment: Sorry about the messed up link. Google changed something a few months back (and this pointed to my folder instead of the file), and I forget that sometimes. I believe it's right now.

Comment: @njuffa, thanks for your reply. The facts about these mathematicians are not clear, and anyone who is an expert will know the specific focused questions implied by giving their names. There might be a dozen questions total about the sequence of events that led to the cubic formula (and later the creation of complex numbers).

Comment: @SueVanHattum The problem with the "messed-up link" demonstrates another issue here: Just as link-only answers can become meaningless due to link rot, this also applies to questions. Good questions are self-contained, with links in a supporting role. If there are multiple questions to be resolved, they can certainly be asked on this site as multiple questions. It will help with reception if the asker shows research effort.

Comment: Since this part is about 15 pages long, I'm not sure how that would work. I will try to find math historians elsewhere, and if not successful, will try to break it up as you suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote:

> Rafael Bombelli ... did show that you could simplify the mess we have
> up there on the whiteboard, and get x = 4.

This is the central point of many popular stories about cubic equations. But this is just not true. If Cardano formula have square roots of negative numbers, you can't just simplify it  to get rid of them and calculate the roots. So, if your goal is to actually calculate the roots of this particular cubic, then Cardano's formula is pretty useless. Sorry. Luca Pacioli was right after all - there is no general formula for cubic equations that uses radicals, at least in the sense known to Luca.

Here is an idea for your story to illustrate this point (sorry for taking liberty of using your character):

Althea accidentally travels back in time. She meets Ptolemy who is very excited to hear that cubic equations could be solved. Ptolemy is trying to compose trig table and wants to calculate $\cos 20°$. He knows $\cos 60°$ and knows the formula for $\cos(3x)$. So he knows that $\cos 20°$ is the solution of the equation
$$4x^3 - 3x = \frac 1 2.$$
But how to solve it?
Althea is very happy that she can help. She writes down the solution:
$$x = \frac 1 2 \left (
\sqrt[3]{\frac 1 2 + \frac {\sqrt {-3}} {2} } +
\sqrt[3]{\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt {-3}} {2} } 
\right)
$$
Unfortunately Ptolemy is not used to our algebraic notations.
It took Althea a week to explain him what all symbols in the formula means, and finally Ptolemy starts to understand. But then Ptolemy noticed $\sqrt{-3}$. And asks what is it? Althea have to explain complex numbers. (But first of course she needs to explain negative numbers). It took a month, but Ptolemy is very patient, because he is eager to learn the science of the future to complete his trig table and to use it for his astronomy calculations. Finally he become fluent with complex numbers.

"But how do we calculate a cubic root of $ \frac 1 2 + \frac {\sqrt {3}} {2} i$?".

"We almost there! To calculate a cubic root of a complex number, you need to take a cubic root of its length and divide its angle by 3. You are in luck: the number $ \frac 1 2 + \frac {\sqrt {3}} {2} i $ has a very nice length: it is just 1. Cubic root of 1 is 1. And is has a very nice angle: it's just 60°. So the cubic root is just a number with the length 1 and the angle 20°. It's just $\cos 20^\circ +i \sin 20^\circ$. Is it nice?"

At this point Ptolemy understands that the future science is just a fraud and he just wasted his valuable time.

Comment: Thank you! If that's the only error you can find, I'm thrilled. I enjoyed your Althea story, even though it won't work with my Althea story.

My understanding was that Bombelli figured that the two parts must be complements and would therefore add to 4. This page explains some of what he did, but there is circular reasoning in it. (After lots of work, "obvious solution a=2", when the original has an obvious solution of x=4. But he did show that the formula matches with what we knew before.)  http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/eqns_4.pdf

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you already know solution,  then you can verify that Cordano formula works. But in general, if you want to find $\sqrt[3]{a+ib}$, you will end up with... cubic equation.  And Galois theory proves that you can't express roots with real radicals. Of course you can also use trigonometry. In fact there is a [trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric%20solution%20for%20three%20real%20roots) for cubic equations that was found independently by Viète.

Comment: Do you disagree with the reasoning given here? http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/12/bombelli-and-invention-of-complex.html

Comment: I don't disagree with what is written there. However, it is important to note that this is an explanation how complex numbers work. It does not help you to solve cubic equations. They reduce the equation $x^3 = 15x + 4$ to a system in item (4). But this system is not easier to solve than the original equation. They solve it in (5) assuming there is an integer solution. But you can do it using the Rational root theorem for the original equation. You don't need cubic formula for that. Moreover cubic formula or complex number do not make it easier.