# Who is the artist who depicted Tartaglia?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

I mentioned [in a previous question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14498/request-readers-to-check-accuracy-of-the-history-in-my-young-adult-math-story) that I'm writing a young adult novel that explores the discovery of complex numbers. I  might want to include an illustration of Tartaglia. All of the [illustrations I see](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=APwXEdfEuBzMOgd2BcrUKcML0_EPHq8RqQ:1687230037780&q=tartaglia%20mathematician&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFpbnY7dD_AhW5ADQIHSFCDXQQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1427&bih=764&dpr=2) when I google look similar to one another. I'd like to figure out who created the original image(s), and so far have had no luck.

Who created this depiction (or these depictions)?

Comment: Did you check this museum webpage in Netherland? It is dated to 1572. Click on "More details" https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/en/collection/RP-P-1909-4459

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if the 2nd name (Benedictus Arias Montanus) is the artist.

Comment: Hmm, it was done 15 years after he died. I wonder how accurate a portrayal it is.

Comment: Nobody can believe the accurate potraits of the 15th century or even 21st century. That will always have human imagination.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps: A portrait of Tartaglia appears as the [frontispiece](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quesiti_et_inventioni_diverse_de_Nicolo/KaJmAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) of the book *Quesiti et Inventioni diverse de Nicolo Tartaglia* from 1554. Since Tartaglia died in 1557, this is *presumably* an accurate portrayal drawn from real life. Wikimedia Commons also provides a scan [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Title_page_of_Quesit_et_inventioni_diverse;_with_half_length_portrait_of_the_author,_mathematician_Nicolo_Tartaglia_LCCN92518243.jpg).

Comment: So this one is different from the other! Thank you! They looked almost the same to me. Perhaps the later artist had access to this.

Comment: I did look hard before asking. I appreciate you both helping me find these dates.

Comment: @Sue VanHattum Note that the first edition of the book, *Quesiti et Inventioni diverse de Nicolo Tartalea Brisciano* dates to 1546, and includes essentially the same portrait, as seen in [this scan](https://library.si.edu/image-gallery/99528) from the Smithsonian. The inscription at the bottom of the portrait uses the spelling "Tartalea" (presumably due to non-standardized spelling, or as a local spelling variant). There is also a line of text at the base of the portrait, which *may* mention the artist, but I have not been able to find a scan where that line is actually readable.

Comment: After staring at a number of Google images for a while I think that the text at the base mentioned by @njuffa reads: "invenzioni sono difficile ma lo aggiungervi è facile". Google translates this as: "inventions are difficult but adding to them is easy". So no painter name (but there is still some illegible scribble at the very right).

Comment: [Montanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benito_Arias_Montano) was not an artist, he is the [author of Latin verses](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/P_1864-0309-65) under the portrait. Rijksmuseum puts "after design by" for the artist when known. It appears that all online portraits are engravings by [Galle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Galle) or Locatelli after Tartaglia's death. [Some of them](https://www.bridgemanimages.com/en-US/unknown-artist/nicolo-niccolo-tartaglia-1499-1557-italian-mathematician/nomedium/asset/4771313) list the original artist as "unknown".

Comment: Another interesting [tidbit of Tartaglia's biography](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/who-is-tartaglia-really-do-not-call-nicolo-tartaglia-fontana) that may interest you, Fontana was not his last name. Brixianus under the portrait was not either, it just indicated that his family was from Brescia. [SciHi](http://scihi.org/niccolo-tartaglia/) has some more details and references on the solving the cubics story.